# Failed opening required 'Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase.php'

Tags: smarty

I'm using smarty version 3.1.13;
My project works perfectly on the local server;
When I put my site on the server (www.1and1.com) appears the following error:

```
 Fatal error: require_once():
 Failed opening required 'Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase.php' 
(include_path='/homepages/39/d441258317/htdocs/mtx/application:/
 homepages/39/d441258317/htdocs/mtx/application/controllers:
 /homepages/39/d441258317/htdocs/mtx/application/models:
 /homepages/39/d441258317/htdocs/mtx/application/../library:
 /homepages/39/d441258317/htdocs/mtx/application/../library/Smarty
 /sysplugins:/homepages/39/d441258317/htdocs/mtx/application/../library
 /Smarty/plugins:.:/usr/lib/php6') in /homepages/39/d441258317/htdocs/
 mtx/index.php on line 28
```

I changed the permissions of the folder compile_c but nothing, still get an error

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

looks like a big problem but was not. When i created my folder in local server  did i put "public" folder with "P" upercase. Because i have a linux server and linux it's case sensitive it not works. Just rename the folder from "Public" to "public" and it done!